# How to get the session's data of date with `request.session.get()` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions, django-request

I could get the session's data of data with `request.session['key']['key']` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    request.session['person'] = {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session['person']['name']) # John
    print(request.session['person']['age']) # 27
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, I couldn't get the session's data of data with [request.session.get('key/key')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get) as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    request.session['person'] = {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session.get('person/name')) # None
    print(request.session.get('person/age')) # None
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, how can I get the session's data of data with `request.session.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session of session with [request.session.get('key')['key']](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get) as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    request.session['person'] = {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session.get('person')['name']) # John
    print(request.session.get('person')['age']) # 27
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```